# Updating SOAP data into SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: xml, sharepoint, synchronization

I have two web services one is SOAP and the other is RSS Rest - using SharePoint designer I can pull the whole SOAP data into an ASPx page but it is just a big lump of data! I need it organized in a list and eventually need to be able to synch that list with user profiles in SharePoint.

how can I do that? any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample of the data 
JodyAnnChekaraJohnFemalejfgfoto@wdigi.comPASActiveLEGALLegal and Compliance4210

Comment: This question is too broad. Search for XSLT or JavaScript solutions. This might be a good startpoint: http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: How can I read the SOAP data and pump it into a sharePoint list? it is now a huge xml file all in one big lump

Comment: there are several ways, see the above link for some examples.